# xmpp group communication

Tags: android, client, xmpp

i implemented the xmpp client in android.its working fine.the next task i focused on group communication from android.please anybody help me in the java code which related to group communication from xmpp.

thnku in advance

regards
renuka

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read [XEP-45](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/documentation.jsp) API, check out how to use the Multi User Chat API [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html)